# SQL SELECT QUERY - from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I faced a difficult problem about SQL query.
Please help me

I have two tables like below.

```
TABLE_A                   TABLE_B
Date      Value_A         Date      Value_B
20180201   52             20180131   120
20180202   50             20180201   114
20180205   48             20180203   127
20180206   57             20180204   140
20180207   60             20180206   129
```

And I want to get this result.

```
Date       Value_A     PreValue_B
20180201    52          120
20180202    50          114
20180205    48          140
20180206    57          140
20180207    60          129
```

Date and Value_A are the same as TABLE_A.
PreValue_B is from Value_B.
But it is the value of the maximum (closest) & previous date of TABLE_B.

so, the closest previous date of 20180201 of TABLE_B is "20180131".
...

the closest previous date of 20180205 is "20180204", so PreValue_B is 140.

20180206 is "20180204", so PreValue_B is 140 again.
and so on...

How to make the SQL Query?

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Please tag your DBMS (mysql, sql server, oracle, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical approach uses correlated subqueries:

```
select a.*,
       (select b.value
        from b
        where b.date < a.date
        order by b.date desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as prevalue_b
from a;
```

This uses the ANSI standard method for limiting to one row.  Some databases spell this as `limit` or `select top 1`.

Comment: what is `fetch first 1 row only`? I never saw that in SQL.

Comment: GREAT! Thanks Gordon!

Comment: @Sirmyself I changed "fetch first 1 row only" to "limit 1" , and it works well.

Comment: @b-a Thanks. But still, where does it come from? ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT sub.date, sub.a, b.b
FROM
(SELECT a.date, a.a, MAX(b.date) AS b_date
 FROM a
 INNER JOIN b
 ON (a.date > b.date)
 GROUP BY a.date, a.a) sub
INNER JOIN b
ON sub.b_date = b.date
ORDER BY sub.date
```

In the sub-query, find the date that should be selected in b for each date in a. Then join the results back to b, in order to show the b value.

Tested here: http://rextester.com/ERP28040

Comment: thanks, I don't understand what "inner join" is, but I won't forget and will learn soon.